# delete several files but leave the selected one

Tags: 12.04, rm

I have a folder contenting several folders and I hope to delete all of them but leave one selected, how could I do this with the command "rm "under Ubuntu12.04??

Comment: How many are those folders ?

Comment: Similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325216/rm-all-files-except-some

Answer (score 1):

As by deleting files one can get into serious problems, I would recomend moving unwanted files to some folder before deleting them from the disk. Let's create folder `wastebasket` and place it in `~`:

```
mkdir ~/wastebasket/
```

Then, let's `cd` to the folder, which requires cleaning, and move all files except one, named `precious`, to `wastebasket`:

```
cd mess/
ls -1 | grep -xv precious | xargs -i mv -i {} ~/wastebasket/
```

If everything went as expected, delete the `wastebasket`:

```
rm -rf wastebasket
```

Answer (score 0):

If the file is in the current directory you can just do:

```
for file in *; do if [ $file != 'NAME_OF_YOUR_FILE' ]; then rm -r $file; fi; done
```

Warning: May cause loss of valuable data, not tested with files that have special characters, spaces, new lines, zero characters, names of american presidents.